# dhtmlxToolbar button text style

Tags: toolbar, dhtmlx

How can I set bold style for dhtmlxToolbar button text using xml?
I.e. this is my item:

```
<item type="button" id="btn" text="button text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
<item type="button" id="btn" text="&lt;span style='font-weight:bold'&gt;button text&lt;/span&gt;"/>
```